# Java, How to convert decimal number as string into an integer

Tags: java, string, integer

I have a text file with decimal numbers in it.  I am trying to use `Integer.valueOf()` in a Java program and it does not convert the decimal numbers.

How do I convert the decimal number string into an int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use java's `Double.valueOf()` [defined here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28double%29) instead; then you can convert the resulting double to an int.